# Extract string within parentheses - PYTHON

Tags: python, string, split, extract

I have a string "Name(something)" and I am trying to extract the portion of the string within the parentheses!

Iv'e tried the following solutions but don't seem to be getting the results I'm looking for.

```
n.split('()')

name, something = n.split('()')
```

Answer (score 32):

You can use a simple regex to catch everything between the parenthesis:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Name(something)'
>>> re.search('\(([^)]+)', s).group(1)
'something'
```

The regex matches the first "(", then it matches everything that's *not* a ")":

- `\(` matches the character "(" literally
- the capturing group `([^)]+)` greedily matches anything that's not a ")"

Comment: Thanks! makes sense, however i'm getting the error that re is not defined, do you need to import a library for this function?

Comment: @olly_t `import re`

Answer (score 17):

as an improvement on @Maroun Maroun 's answer:

```
re.findall('\(([^)]+)', s)
```

it finds all instances of strings in between parentheses

Comment: This gives me a `SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('` :-(

Answer (score 5):

You can use split as in your example but this way

```
val = s.split('(', 1)[1].split(')')[0]
```

or using regex

Comment: i/p cmd = (0, 45, -4, -9) after print('cmd =',cmd.split('(', 1)[1].split(')')[0]) o/p cmd = 0, 45, -4, -9

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.match`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "name(something)"
>>> na, so = re.match(r"(.*)\((.*)\)" ,s).groups()
>>> na, so
('name', 'something')
```

that matches two `(.*)` which means anything, where the second is between parentheses `\(` & `\)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for `(` and `)` (need to escape these using backslash in regex) and then match every character using `.*` (capturing this in a group).

Example:

```py
import re

s = "name(something)"

regex = r'\((.*)\)'

text_inside_paranthesis = re.match(regex, s).group(1)

print(text_inside_paranthesis)
```

Outputs:

```
something
```

---

Without regex you can do the following:

```py
text_inside_paranthesis =  s[s.find('(')+1:s.find(')')]
```

Outputs:

```
something
```