# Regex Python find everything between four characters

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string that holds data. And I want everything in between **({ and })**

```
"({Simple Data})"
```

Should return "Simple Data"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract string within parentheses - PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999344/extract-string-within-parentheses-python)

Comment: @U9-Forward I believe this question is about tokenizer and parser if it involves nesting structures.

Answer (score 0):

If the brackets are always positioned at the beginning and the end of the string, then you can do this:

```
l = "({Simple Data})"
print(l[2:-2])
```

Which resulst in:

```
"Simple Data"
```

In Python you can access single characters via the [] operator. With this you can access the sequence of characters starting with the third one (index = 2) up to the second-to-last (index = -2, second-to-last is not included in the sequence).

Comment: @U9-Forward That is why I specified that this solution is valid if the brackets are always positioned at the end and the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Or regex:

```
s = '({Simple Data})'
print(re.search('\({([^})]+)', s).group(1))
```

Output:

```
'Simple Data'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hereby I designed a tokenizer aimming at nesting data. OP should check out [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=flags#writing-a-tokenizer).

```
import collections
import re

Token = collections.namedtuple('Token', ['typ', 'value', 'line', 'column'])

def tokenize(code):
    token_specification = [
        ('DATA',        r'[ \t]*[\w]+[\w \t]*'),
        ('SKIP',        r'[ \t\f\v]+'),
        ('NEWLINE',     r'\n|\r\n'),
        ('BOUND_L',     r'\(\{'),
        ('BOUND_R',     r'\}\)'),
        ('MISMATCH',    r'.'),
    ]
    tok_regex = '|'.join('(?P<%s>%s)' % pair for pair in token_specification)
    line_num = 1
    line_start = 0
    lines = code.splitlines()
    for mo in re.finditer(tok_regex, code):
        kind = mo.lastgroup
        value = mo.group(kind)
        if kind == 'NEWLINE':
            line_start = mo.end()
            line_num += 1
        elif kind == 'SKIP':
            pass
        else:
            column = mo.start() - line_start
            yield Token(kind, value, line_num, column)

statements = '''
    ({Simple Data})
    ({
        Parent Data Prefix
        ({Nested Data (Yes)})
        Parent Data Suffix
    })
'''

queue = collections.deque()

for token in tokenize(statements):
    if token.typ == 'DATA' or token.typ == 'MISMATCH':
        queue.append(token.value)
    elif token.typ == 'BOUND_L' or token.typ == 'BOUND_R':
        print(''.join(queue))
        queue.clear()
```

Output of this code should be:

```
Simple Data
    Parent Data Prefix
Nested Data (Yes)
    Parent Data Suffix
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
^\({(.*)}\)$
```

Group 1 will contain `Simple Data`.

See an [example on regexr](https://regexr.com/3ub9m).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex `(?s)\(\{(.*?)\}\)`
which simply captures the contents between the delimiters.

Beware though, this doesn't account for nesting.

If nesting is a concern, the best you can to with standard Python `re` engine
is to get the inner nest only, using this regex:

`\(\{((?:(?!\(\{|\}\).)*)\}\)`