# How to parse until a certain part of text and dump the rest into a json file

Tags: python, parsing

I have the result of a shell command as a string. I want to parse the string so that the dictionary object alone is saved in a json file.

```
s = "output/directory/366d595b-23b2-435d-8dc6-698b3d0844b9/result.csv scores=[{
   "base_score": 0.92,
   "metric": "ACCURACY"
    }]
```

I tried the below approach to parse after the "=" but I am not sure that is robust.

```
i = iter(s)
a = '-'.join(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != '=', i))

print(a)

with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dumps(data, outfile)

    json.dumps(a, indent=4)
```

Comment: Can you format the string s properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a regular expression.

```
import json
import re

s = '''output/directory/366d595b-23b2-435d-8dc6-698b3d0844b9/result.csv scores=[ 
     {
   "base_score": 0.92,
   "metric": "ACCURACY"
    }]'''

import json
import re

dict_txt = re.search('\[([^]]+)', s).group(1).strip()
data = json.loads(dict_txt)
print(data)
```

The regular expression is similar to that described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38999572/9658263).

Comment: thanks for this. How do I modify the regex if the string is an object from a list. So there are no quotes. Does it become dict_txt = re.search(\[([^]]+), s).group(1).strip()

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the string being an object from a list? The regex just returns everything found between the square brackets. I recommend using an online tester to understand and check your regex expressions. E.g. [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KePfMd/1).

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
import json

s = '''output/directory/366d595b-23b2-435d-8dc6-698b3d0844b9/result.csv scores=[
     {
   "base_score": 0.92,
   "metric": "ACCURACY"
    }]'''

data = json.loads(s.split('=')[1])
print(data)
with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp)
```

That will split the string on the `=` and then parse the second element.